# How to change apache php version

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos6

I have a centos 6 vm as my development environment and came with php5.3.3 By this I mean I use yum to install php (yum install php)

I install php 5.4 with these instructions http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php54/

In command line (php -v) I have 5.4 but with apache I still have 5.3 (phpinfo())

I have looked and looked but I can't find a 5.4.so file that I can point apache to.

How do I get apache to use the 5.4 version?

```
#>yum list installed | grep php
php54w.x86_64          5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-cli.x86_64      5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-common.x86_64   5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-devel.x86_64    5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-gd.x86_64       5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-mbstring.x86_64 5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-mysql.x86_64    5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-pdo.x86_64      5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic                               
php54w-pear.noarch     1:1.9.4-7.w6     @webtatic                               
php54w-soap.x86_64     5.4.19-1.w6      @webtatic
```

In my case there is no php configuration in http.conf but all *.conf files are included in conf.d folder. In the conf.d folder there is a php.conf and it contains.

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule !worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Comment: When you say it came with 5.3.3 what do you mean. Was it installed as a package (if so you should be able to remove it). More information would be helpful.

Comment: Add the output of "# yum list installed | grep php" to the question

Comment: Questing updated as requested

Comment: Have you restarted apache since installing the php 5.4 RPMs?

Comment: Yes I have with apachectl restart. I have also done a complete OS reboot

Comment: What about rpm -qf /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache2 configuration (or vhost config, depending on your setup) there is a setting that selects the PHP version to use. As you configured apache with php 5.3, you have to change this to the new PHP version, something like this;

```
ScriptAlias /php5.3 /usr/local/php5.3/bin 
Action application/php5.3 /php5.3/php-cgi
AddType application/php5.3 .php
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more information.